# Is there any vim plugins written in python?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

Just like Command-T. Command-T  requires Vim compiled with Ruby support. Is there any vim plugin written in python?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec / off site resource.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many:

- https://github.com/klen/rope-vim
- https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips

You can find 90+ more on Github by querying the `username:vim-scripts` for `language:python` (meaning Python is the primary language):

- https://github.com/search?q=language%3Apython+username%3Avim-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please refer to my plugin:
https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF.
Its function is similar to Command-T, yet written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can see reworked [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline): it has exactly 19+3 meaningful lines in two *.vim files (total 31+11: with empty lines and some auxiliary things). File with 3 (11) lines is not required if you install plugin using `pip`. In any case it is required to add one additional line to the vimrc.

It is the only vim plugin I know that has *that* less number of lines in `*.vim` files.